# Defer in my app.js in laravel is not letting my javascript code work

Tags: javascript, laravel, deferred

Even though I have my entire code in javascript until I remove the defer from my app.js it does not work. Is there a reason for it?

> **Edit**
> I added my whole blade.php file here the javascript in at the bottom is being extended from my add.blade.php file. The javascript code is also yielded from my add.blade.php file.

> **Here is my blade file**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('style')
    <link href="{{ asset('css/Admin/sql-data-viewer.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">   
@endsection
@section('content')
<?php ?>
    <section class="data-viewer">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between px-3">
        <h3>Select Banner to change</h3>
      <a href="{{URL::Current()}}/create"><button type="button" class="btn add-data text-white rounded-pill">Add Banner &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button></a>
      </div>
    <form method="post">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
      @if(session()->has('message'))
      <div class="alert alert-success">
          {{ session()->get('message') }}
      </div>
      @endif 
      <div class="delete pl-3 mt-3 mb-3">
        <label for="deleteSelected">Action:</label>
        <select name="deleteSelected" id="deleteSelected" class="@error('deleteSelected') is-invalid @enderror" name="deleteSelected" >
          <option disabled selected>---------</option>
          <option>Delete Selected Banner</option>
        </select>
      <button formaction="{{ route('banners.delete') }}" type="submit" class="go" id="deleleGo" onclick="deleteBtn()">Go</button> 
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="selected">0</span> of {{$showCounts}} selected
      @error('deleteSelected')
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
          <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
      </span>
      @enderror
      </div>
      <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-dark">
      <div id="selectError"><p>You must check at least one checkbox</p></div>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col"><input type="checkbox" id="checkHead" class="selectall"></th>
            <th scope="col">Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Image</th>
            <th scope="col">Caption Heading</th>
            <th scope="col">Caption Description</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          @foreach ($banners as $banner)
          <tr>
            <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" class="selectbox" value="{{ $banner->id }}" onchange="change()"></th>
            <td onClick="location.href='{{URL::current()}}/{{Str::slug($banner->id) }}/edit'" style="cursor: pointer">{{$banner->id}}</td>
            <td onClick="location.href='{{URL::current()}}/{{Str::slug($banner->id) }}/edit'" style="cursor: pointer"><img src="/storage/{{$banner->Banner_Image}}" alt="{{$banner->Caption_Heading}}" class="img-thumbnail" width="70px" height="100px"></td>
            <td onClick="location.href='{{URL::current()}}/{{Str::slug($banner->id) }}/edit'" style="cursor: pointer">{{$banner->Caption_Heading}}</td>
            <td onClick="location.href='{{URL::current()}}/{{Str::slug($banner->id) }}/edit'" style="cursor: pointer">{{$banner->Caption_Description}}</td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
  </section>
@endsection

@section('script')
<script>
const all = document.getElementById("checkHead");
all.addEventListener('click',toogle);
function toogle() {
  const isChecked = all.checked;
  Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('input')).forEach(element =>{
    element.checked = isChecked;
  });
}
function change(){
  var total = document.getElementsByClassName('selectbox').length;
  var number = document.querySelectorAll('.selectbox:checked').length;
  if(total === number){
    document.getElementById("checkHead").checked = true;
  } else{
    document.getElementById("checkHead").checked = false;
  }
  document.getElementById("selected").innerHTML = number;
}
function deleteBtn(){
  checked = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;

  if(!checked) {
    var a = document.getElementById("selectError").style.display = "block";
    return false;
  }
};
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Do you have any error in your JS console ? What _does not work_ exactly ? What happend that should not happen, or what is not happening that should happen. Have you used breakpoint to do some debugging yourself ?

Comment: @Nicolas nothing except when I remove defer from app.js then the there us vue warn but then the js code works and if I add defer no error.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably happening because you are trying to get an element which is not there at the time this script runs. Make sure you include the javascript on bottom of the page if you don't want to defer it.

Comment: I have added my blade.php file above instead of just my javascript code can you look at it.

Comment: and where is tthe script section included? which part of the layout?

Comment: I fixed this problem since I was not using vue.js I made a new laravel application without vue and transferred my code there now it is working